# How can I connect to Oracle using yii2?

Tags: php, oracle, yii2

There is **main-local.php** file :

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//[db_host:db_port]/[dbname]',
        'username' => '***',
        'password' => '***',
    ]
```

When I tried first time connect to DB, there was an error "driver not found". After I installed a driver, there is the following error :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[]: (null)
>   Caused by: PDOException

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRl5O.png)

Please help.

Comment: try changing to `localhost` look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279984/how-i-can-connect-to-oracle-database-with-yii2/50283791#50283791) if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle Database, the charset must be specified in the `dsn` :

So your dsn should be like :

```
'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//[db_host:db_port]/[dbname];charset=UTF8',
```

or try :

```
'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//[db_host:db_port]/[dbname];charset=UTF-8',
```

Please check manual here -  [Charset Detail](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#$charset-detail) and [Discussion](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/oracle-and-yii2/77797/2?u=akshaypjoshi):

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added `charset=UTF8` but it did not help me. The same problem

Comment: Have you tried to print `phpinfo()` and checked whether your Oracle drivers are loaded properly?

Comment: yes, it is - `Oracle (OCI) driver for PDO - Wez Furlong`

Answer (score 0):

The error `PDOException: SQLSTATE[]: (null) Caused by: PDOException` isn't particularly useful.

Try running standalone PDO_OCI example and see if you get a better error:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // In PHP 5.3 use E_ALL|E_STRICT
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost/orclpdb;charset=AL32UTF8', 'hr', 'hrpassword',
           array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$s = $dbh->prepare("select sysdate from dual");
$s->execute();
while ($r = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $r['SYSDATE'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did as you showed, but there is the same error `SQLSTATE[]: (null)`

Comment: How did you install PDO_OCI?

Comment: just downloaded driver from oracle's web-site, placed it into apache/bin and php/ext. After uncommented it in php.ini

Comment: 'oracle's web-site'?  which one?  What operating system.  The more info you give, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8 - that site. 2.1.3 version x64 php 7.0 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64

Comment: (a) that is OCI8, not PDO_OCI (b) that is not an Oracle web site.

Comment: Best to update your original post with all the details about what you downloaded and what you changed in php.ini etc. That way we can help.

Comment: Okay. Which one can you recommend?